# Docusign edit/sender views temporarily return to home screen before redirect

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using an asp.net app to create an envelope with signers, return the edit or sender views to the user, passing it a return URL so when the signature tagging is done, it goes back to my site.

Technically, it works, but the problem is after you click SEND, it temporarily takes you back to your "home/management" page showing all your folders such as Inbox, Draft, etc for about 2 seconds before finally redirecting you back to the URL specified earlier.

Is there any way to block this activity so it immediately goes back to the returnURL immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question Brian.

This is what we call "by design" as this is the behavior everyone sees.
Is there any reason that bothers you so much? it is for about 1-2 seconds, most users don't notice it.
If you want, you can load it in the background, and only make it visible 2 seconds later to ensure it's not shown quickly to your users. 
I am not sure the technical reason this works like this, but this is a limitation we have right now.